# Using PowerShell to execute a remote script that calls a batch file

Tags: powershell, selenium, batch-file

I am having an issue with running a batch file that is located on a remote server.

I have a batch file located on a remote server that i want to run that kicks off an automated Selenium test.  For simplicity, let's say the name of my batch file is mybatch.bat

I have the following code in a Powershell script located on the  server:

```
$BatchFile = "mybatch.bat"

Start-Process -FilePath $BatchFile -Wait  -Verb RunAs
```

If I run this PowerShell script locally on the server in ISE then it runs fine and it kicks off the selenium test which takes a couple minutes to run.

Now I want to try to execute this test from another machine by using PowerShell remoting.  Let's assume that remoting is already configured on the servers.

I have a PowerShell script located on another server which has the following code segment. Assume that all of the session variables have the correct information set:

```
$CMD = "D:\mybatch.bat"

$TargetSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $FullComputerName -Credential $myCreds -ConfigurationName RemoteExecution

$command = "powershell.exe -File $CMD -Wait"
Invoke-Command -Session $TargetSession -ScriptBlock { $command }
```

When this script runs, it does connect to the remote machine and create a remote session.  It does look like it kicks off the batch file because PowerShell does not give me an error. But it does not wait for the full 3 or 4 minutes for the Selenium test to finish. It seems like it just times out. Also if I am logged onto the other machine, I don't see any Selenium web test running.  No Selenium log files or results files are created on remote server as should be expected.

I was wondering what I could be doing wrong with my code.

Also, it seems that the server always returns the echo outputs of the batch file to my local machine.  I see these random blinking white screen on ISE which looks like output from the batch file

Comment: add some logging to your script. i suspect you are seeing the "double hop" problem ... and attempting to access the BAT file is getting an access denied error.

Answer (score 1):

```
$command = "powershell.exe -File $CMD -Wait"
Invoke-Command -Session $TargetSession -ScriptBlock { $command }
```

There are 2 issues with the above code:

- `$command` inside the scriptblock and `$command` outside the scriptblock are different variables due to different scopes. The variable inside the scriptblock is thus undefined and the scriptblock will simply echo an emtpy value.
- Even if `$command` weren't undefined, the scriptblock would still just echo its value, since it's defined as a string. PowerShell does not execute strings unless you're using something like `Invoke-Expression` ([which you shouldn't](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)).

This should do what you want:

```
$CMD = "D:\mybatch.bat"

$TargetSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $FullComputerName -Credential $myCreds -ConfigurationName RemoteExecution  

Invoke-Command -Session $TargetSession -ScriptBlock { & $using:CMD }
```

Comment: Ansgar, thank you for your help.  The new Invoke-Command does seem to kick off the remote Powershell script because I am seeing output loggging information on my ISE script.  But my selenium batch file does not seem to kick off.     Should I try using Invoke-Command on the Powershell script on the remote server too?  Something like this:  Invoke-Command  -ScriptBlock { & using:$BatchFile }

Comment: I had to change the execution of the batch file in the remote Powershell to this syntax to work:   & $BatchFile

Answer (score 0):

If you would like execute a bat file from another machine by using PowerShell Remote Session, simply enter **dot** and then follow by a whitespace, then enter the exact path of bat file located on that remote machine.

**Example**

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteComputerName -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {. "D:\Temp\Install_Something.bat"}
```